# Is there a web service that can list all Sites in a Sharepoint Online tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

Is there a web service that can list all Sharepoint Online top-level sites that exist in a tenant?

For example:

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com

Has

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1

and

https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site2

Is there a way to list site1 and site2 using a soap or rest web service?

If so, what permission is required?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to get a list of the site collections, and if PowerShell is OK:

```
Get-SPOSite
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/?view=sharepoint-ps

Otherwise, I'm not aware of a direct REST query for a list of Site Collections.

You can use the search REST API and search for `contentclass:sts_site`. This is security trimmed, so you will only see the site collections you have permissions for. You can test this from a SharePoint search center to see if it works.

Comment: ah yeah - dupe of https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/what-is-the-rest-endpoint-url-to-get-list-of-site-collections